# Is Intent responsible for launching MainActivity of he application?

Tags: android, android-intent

If Activity manager launches the MainActivity through `intent-filter` with `action=main`, and `category=launcher`, then which type of intent is used?

I'm confused little bit. Is it implicit intent?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: its about internal as programmer we must know about some internals about the system its better to know android in deep can u pls check in internal execution of android pls respond

Comment: i still don't get what you mean by "type of intent"

Comment: intent are 2 type implicit and explicit but the app start then in console u can see:: ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.implicitintent/.ImplicitActivity }                             can u explain that and dont tell that system does kindly response pls

Answer (score 2):

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities.

when the user clicks on the application icon, the android system looks in the manifest file for the intent with

`action="android.intent.action.MAIN"`

and

`category="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER".`

**MAIN action** is the main entry point of the application.

**LAUNCHER category** means it should appear in the Launcher as a top-level application.

Comment: if system look up for manifest file for the intent how come while installing project in emulator then "activity manager:Intent action =main and category=launcher" get displayed on console

Answer (score 1):

Intent is just a piece of information about **intention**. Intent **do not** starts anything. It just inform OS that there is a need to do something (i.e start app). System looks for apps able to resolve this intention, starts them and pases to them starting intent (becouse you can pass some portion of data in it).

When user clicks app icon in launcher, launcher application generates and sens intent to OS (with explicit name of desired application to start). Android creates separate DVM, main activity class, starts acrivity's life cycle with calling onCreate() and brings activity to foreground.

Comment: its all about intent...Then what will happen when the user click on application can u explain

Comment: What do you mean "click on application" click on launch icon?

Comment: doesnt count whether it is click or touch what will happen when application get started what responsible for loading mainactivity

Comment: all android components (activities, services, content providers etc.) are managed by system.

Comment: ofcourse its system but what is role of activity manager,resource manager can u please mention type of intent called by os

Comment: Yes - have you read that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html ?

Comment: have u in that they were mentioning the its an entry after that nothing

Answer (score 1):

When the user selects your app icon from the Home screen, the system calls the **onCreate()** method for the Activity in your app that you've declared to be the "launcher" (or "main") activity. This is the activity that serves as the main entry point to your app's user interface.

You can define which activity to use as the main activity in the Android manifest file, **AndroidManifest.xml**, which is at the root of your project directory.

The main activity for your app must be declared in the manifest with an *intent-filter* that includes the **MAIN** action and LAUNCHER category(That you know probably).

If a component does not have any intent filters, it can receive only explicit intents. A component with filters can receive both explicit and implicit intents.

Therefore, activities that are willing to receive implicit intents must include **"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"** in their intent filters. Filters with **"android.intent.action.MAIN"** and **"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"** settings are the exception. They mark activities that begin new tasks and that are represented on the launcher screen. They can include "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in the list of categories, but don't need to.

For more details please refer this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: did u saw in console there] Starting activity com.example.implicitintent.ImplicitActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-12-12 16:09:54 - ImplicitIntent] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.implicitintent/.ImplicitActivity }

Comment: In above console system involves intent with activity manager i need that particular portion cleared thats all i want Thank u ur kind response im just a beginner pls res

Comment: Can you show me the code along with manifest.xml file please??

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.implicitintent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity

Comment: android:name="com.example.implicitintent.ImplicitActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

Comment: </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.implicitintent.NextActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_next">
            <intent-filter>   <action android:name="nextActivity" />                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/></intent-filter></activity></application></manifest>

Comment: Here, for  com.example.implicitintent.NextActivity, the category is DEFAULT. In this case the implicit intent will be called. Please refer my updated answer.

Comment: im not discussing about the next activity but i m focusing on MainActivity how system will take the first intent and i just found its through activity manager and by an implicit intent  and for making sure see in your console of eclipse whenever the application runs. one more thing if intent is explicit then what is need of intent filter in mainactivity

Comment: Please refer the link I've provided.

Comment: trust me its not in net thats why i m suggest another proof is in ur console

Comment: I think, the story u have posted is not the clarification of my answer. My answer itself is clear to some extent.

Comment: Its not story its fact its in this link people.debian.org.tw/~olv/surfaceflinger/surfaceflinger.pdf

Comment: @Androiduser007 - Please don't completely rewrite another user's answer in a suggested edit. If you have something to add, please do so in a separate answer or a comment.